# while loop causes crashing browser but for loop don't in scroll event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to binary search when scroll event happened (binary search based on while loop)
but when I scroll with mouse wheel, it causes crash browser after some wheel up and down

In contrast when I'm trying linear search based on for loop, it freezed when I scroll up and down fast but it unfreezed so I can see result

I encountered this issue in React's effect hooks(when scrolling occured, effect runs) so at that moment i thought this was react's problem
but I tested in vanilla javascript. It's not react's problem

here's a code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent1">
    <div id="child1"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="parent2">
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
#parent1, #parent2 {
height: 500px;
overflow: scroll;
}

#child1, #child2 {
height: 20000px;
}
```

```js
const parent1 = document.getElementById('parent1');
const parent2 = document.getElementById('parent2');

let array = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  array.push(i);
}

parent1.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }

})

parent2.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let start = 0;
  let end = array.length - 1;
  let middle = Math.round((end - start) / 2);
  let result;
  while (start <= end) {
    if (array[middle] > 5) {
      end = middle - 1;
      middle = Math.round((end - start) / 2);
    } else if (array[middle] < 5) {
      start = middle + 1;
      middle = Math.round((end - start) / 2);
    } else if (array[middle] === 5) {
      result = array[middle];
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

when you scroll upper div (for loop) it freezes sometime but will unfreeze
when you scrll lower div (while loop) it crashes after some wheel control

I tested chrome and firefox. no difference between browsers.

Comment: it is because JS is single-threaded.

Comment: @ilkerkaran but why for loop just freeze and why while loop crashes? I am new to javascript and programming either

Comment: Remember `round` can go up or down.  For a sort of binary chop you will need to be consistent.  either `Math.trunc()` or `Math.ceil()`

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your advise

Comment: This is my fault. I should've added start and end, instead I substract start from end